# How to subtract time in ISOFormat [2018-08-11T12:23:55.627Z] from the Mongodb Database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, openweathermap

Mongoose store time in `ISO` Format like this:

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b6ed55b6a12624b1853b29a"
    },
    "time": {
        "$date": "2018-08-11T12:23:55.627Z"
    },
    "location": "Kathmandu",
    "temperature": 23,
    "description": "moderate rain",
    "humidity": 88,
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to check if the database already has data within 30 Minute time period. Like this

```js
WeatherSchema.countDocuments({
      'location': city,
      'time': {
        $lt: Date.now() - 1.8e+6
      }
```

But the `Date.now()` gives the timestamp in `millisecond` and `Database` has time in `ISO-Format`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another way to add 30 minutes like

```
var date = new Date();
var modifiedDate = new Date();
modifiedDate.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 30);

WeatherSchema.countDocuments({
  'location': city,
  'time': {
   $lt: modifiedDate
}
```

Now, `modifiedDate` is a `Date` object so this will be converted accordingly to ISO Format by mongoose while querying.

Comment: @kiran glad to help :)

Comment: I have tried hard to solve the little issue but can't solve it on my own. It will be very much helpful if you have a look at this. I'm sorry if i am asking too much [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800463/how-to-use-nested-router-get-method-using-express-router-middleware)